Uglyfy js not removing the dead code (unused code) with grunt
So I have a grunt setup which loads tasks from another folder which is like this:
grunt.util._.extend(config, loadConfig('./tasks/configs/', grunt));
Under ./tasks/configs the tasks (the js files) are defined for clean, concat, uglify etc
So concat combines all the files in sources to one single file. And similarly uglify should minify and (remove the dead code). But it's not removing the unused js as I can see in coverage under dev tool for my file homeDependencies.js.
uglify.js looks like following:
Note I added this. But it doesn't seem to work.
options: {
        compress: {
          unused: true,
          dead_code: true // Enables dead code elimination
        }
      },

'use strict';

//
// grunt-contrib-uglify targets
//
module.exports = function () {
  return {

    all: {
      options: {
        compress: {
          unused: true,
          dead_code: true // Enables dead code elimination
        }
      },
      files: {
        '<%= distdir %>/js/homeDependencies.js': ['<%= distdir %>/js/homeDependencies.js']
      },
      
    },
   
    //
    // for dev, concat js, vendor, and templates into app.js
    dist: {
      files: {
        '<%= distdir %>/js/dependencies.js': ['<%= distdir %>/js/overthrow.js',
                                              '<%= distdir %>/js/dateformatter.js',
                                              '<%= distdir %>/js/bower_components.js',
                                              '<%= distdir %>/js/sharedTemplates.js',
                                              '<%= distdir %>/js/script.common.js'
                                              ],
        '<%= distdir %>/js/app.js': '<%= distdir %>/js/app.js',
        '<%= distdir %>/js/home.controller.js': '<%= distdir %>/js/home.controller.js',
        '<%= distdir %>/js/search.controller.js': '<%= distdir %>/js/search.controller.js',
        '<%= distdir %>/js/sharedTemplates.js': '<%= distdir %>/js/sharedTemplates.js',
        '<%= distdir %>/js/gdpr.js':          ['<%= distdir %>/js/gdpr.js']
      }
    }
  };
};



Note that the homeDependecies.js gets created after concat runs and I expect uglify to remove dead code from this. Is this even possible?


Are you sure that your code is "dead"? You should probably include what you have and what you expect to be removed in the question.

@Karl-JohanSjögren So homeDependencies combines several files such as bootstap, jquery.min.js etc. And I can see under coverage it shows 72% unused with sevaral lines marked with red border.

If you read the documentation for UglifyJS dead_code in this case means "unreachable code". Most parts of jquery are for sure reachable even if you don't call into it yourself, and the same goes for bootstrap since they can both be referenced by external scripts. https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS#compress-options

@Karl-JohanSjögren Hmm that's interesting. So why does the coverage under dev tool says those lines are unused? I have attached a screenshot. You can refer to that.

The devtools just reports how much of the code that has been called on the current recorded session. A lot of jquery and bootstrap won't be called on every page, and some of it might just not have been called on the pages you visited while recording. So some of it is probably completely unused on your site, and some is just not used everywhere. Uglify won't know that though and keeps it.
